# Aggregation functions when applied to multiple columns is giving wrong result

Tags: linq, ef-core-2.2

I am using ef core 2.2 and LINQ. I am trying to aggregate multiple columns in the same query. The sql query generated by LINQ is incorrect and is yielding incorrect results.

```
 public async Task<SecondaryInvoiceLProformaTotals> test(int secondaryInvoiceId)
        {
            var query = (_context.SecondaryInvoiceLineItems
                    .Where(i => i.SecondaryInvoiceId == secondaryInvoiceId)
                    .GroupBy(l => new {l.SecondaryInvoiceId})
                    .Select(g => new SecondaryInvoiceLProformaTotals
                    {                
                        SecondaryInvoiceId = g.Key.SecondaryInvoiceId,        
                        SumInvoiceQty = g.Sum(o => o.InvoiceQty),
                        SumMRPAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalMRPAmount),
                        SumSecondaryDiscountAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalSecondaryDiscountAmount),
                        SumSecondaryPrice = g.Sum(o => o.TotalSecondaryPrice),
                        SumIGSTAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalIGSTAmount),
                        SumCGSTAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalCGSTAmount),
                        SumSGSTAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalSGSTAmount),
                        SumAmount = g.Sum(o => o.TotalAmount),
                        SumBasePoints = g.Sum(o => o.TotalBasePoints)
                    })
                    );
            SecondaryInvoiceLProformaTotals ret = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();            
            return ret;
        }
```

SQL query generated by LINQ:

```
SELECT SUM("i"."InvoiceQty") AS "SumInvoiceQty", 
"i"."TotalMRPAmount" AS "SumMRPAmount", 
"i"."TotalSecondaryDiscountAmount" AS "SumSecondaryDiscountAmount", 
"i"."TotalSecondaryPrice" AS "SumSecondaryPrice", 
"i"."TotalIGSTAmount" AS "SumIGSTAmount", 
"i"."TotalCGSTAmount" AS "SumCGSTAmount", 
"i"."TotalSGSTAmount" AS "SumSGSTAmount", 
"i"."TotalAmount" AS "SumAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalBasePoints") AS "SumBasePoints"
      FROM "SecondaryInvoiceLineItems" AS "i"
      WHERE "i"."SecondaryInvoiceId" = 5
      GROUP BY "i"."SecondaryInvoiceId"
      LIMIT 1
```

Expected SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM("i"."InvoiceQty") AS "SumInvoiceQty",
SUM("i"."TotalMRPAmount") AS "SumMRPAmount", SUM("i"."TotalSecondaryDiscountAmount") AS "SumSecondaryDiscountAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalSecondaryPrice") AS "SumSecondaryPrice", 
SUM("i"."TotalIGSTAmount") AS "SumIGSTAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalCGSTAmount") AS "SumCGSTAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalSGSTAmount") AS "SumSGSTAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalAmount") AS "SumAmount", 
SUM("i"."TotalBasePoints") AS "SumBasePoints"
      FROM "SecondaryInvoiceLineItems" AS "i"
      WHERE "i"."SecondaryInvoiceId" = 5
      GROUP BY "i"."SecondaryInvoiceId"
      LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sounds like a provider bug. Which [db provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) are you using? You'd better report it (along with the [mcve]) to the corresponding issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I am using the SQLite provider. Can you please help me locate the issue tracker?

Comment: This is maintained by EF Core (Microsoft), hence I guess you should go to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: Thanks Ivan.
Anyone wanting to follow the issue please refer: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15324